# What is the best dot net unit test framework with visual studio integration?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

What is the best dot net unit test framework with visual studio integration?

Comment: please define best. Cheapest? easiest to code in? fewest lines of code per test?

Answer (score 2):

[Testdriven.net](http://www.testdriven.net/) or [Nunit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) with [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Comment: I think you meant: Nunit with Testdriven.net or resharper :)

Answer (score 1):

MSTest is built into Visual Studio 2008 and is fully integrated, including file deployment options and code coverage source highlighting.

Comment: The interface is a real PITA to use though.

Comment: In what way? I find it similar to NUnit.

Answer (score 1):

[testdriven.net](http://testdriven.net/) gives you unit test integration in VS for pretty much any framework you want to use.